# Discrepancy Between ORACLE_UNQNAME, db_unique_name, and v$database Causing OEM Startup Issues

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am experiencing an issue with Oracle 11g where the `ORACLE_UNQNAME`, `db_unique_name`, and the name from `v$database` are not aligned, causing problems with Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM) startup and database connectivity.

Here are the specifics of the problem:

1. `ORACLE_UNQNAME` is set to a different value than what's defined as `db_unique_name` in the database configuration.
2. The instance is currently up and running, and I am able to access it without any issues.
3. OEM fails to start up with the current `ORACLE_UNQNAME`, expecting files in a path that includes the `db_unique_name` instead.
4. When I change `ORACLE_UNQNAME` to match the `db_unique_name`, OEM starts successfully, but then it fails to recognize the running database, suggesting a recovery.
5. Moreover, once the `ORACLE_UNQNAME` is changed to match `db_unique_name`, SQL*Plus is unable to connect to the instance, even though it is running (reverting `ORACLE_UNQNAME` restores connectivity).

To give you a clear picture, here are the relevant outputs:

- Current `ORACLE_UNQNAME`:

  ```bash
  echo $ORACLE_UNQNAME
  PRODRAC
  ```
- db_unique_name from configuration:

  ```sql
  SELECT name, db_unique_name FROM v$database;

  NAME      DB_UNIQUE_NAME
  --------- ------------------------------
  PROD      racvm
  ```

This is a production database, so I am looking for a safe way to resolve this mismatch without causing downtime. My questions are:

Why would there be a discrepancy between these values in the first place?
How can I safely reconcile these values so that OEM can start up properly and recognize the running instance?
Are there any logs or additional diagnostics that I should review to understand why OEM is behaving this way?
I am looking to understand the implications of changing the ORACLE_UNQNAME and how it should be correctly synced with db_unique_name, considering the issues I am facing with OEM.

Any insights or steps for troubleshooting this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.